# Fetching only user's activity in a specific group

Tags: yammer

Is it possible to retrieve only user's activity in a specified group using Yammer REST API?

For example I can retrieve user's activity in a specific network using following query:

```
https://www.yammer.com/{network-name}/api/v1/messages/sent.json
```

It would be great if something like this can be done for group, because for now the only option I found is to use following query:

```
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/in_group/{group-id}.json
```

But it allows to retrieve **all** activity in a particular group, so I will need to do filter user's data by myself.